# MongoDB Sharding slows down queries by 40-120%!

Tags: performance, mongodb, sharding

I'm in the middle of testing sharding on MongoDB as my subset of a collections is growing rapidly and looking for a way to speed up the queries. Like the idea of sharding to be able to use multiple threads on a single query to speed it up.

Now I found out that when you enable sharding, or actually add a shardkey to a collection, the query response times increased significantly by `40%` to `100%`, only when the query is done on the mongos instead of mongod. Got constent results, so I set up a test where maybe you can help me out why it's slower and what I did wrong, or if it's a nasty bug/problem with Mongo sharding.

1. Start an empty configserver
2. Start an empty mongod
3. Start mongos
4. Connect to mongos
5. use testdb
6. add data: `for(var i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {   db.testcol.insert({field1: i}); }`
7. add index: `db.testcol.ensureIndex({field1:1})`
8. Test query speed a couple of times: `db.testcol.find({field1:{$gte: 0}}).explain();`
   On my test system I got a consistent `300 ms`
9. enable sharding: `sh.enableSharding("testdb.testcol");`
10. Test query speed: still `300 ms`
11. shard collection: `sh.shardCollection("testdb.testcol", {field1:1})`
12. Test query speed again a couple of times: Now I'm getting a consistent `660 ms` response time!!!! What happened here? I get exactly the same result set, but now with a significant higher response time. And everything is localhost.
13. Now directly connect to mongod
14. `use testdb`
15. test with the same query: `db.testcol.find({field1:{$gte: 0}}).explain();`
    You will see 300ms response times. So after sharding a collection response times through mongos will be significantly higher. You need 2 machines to get equal response times as before sharding. That shouldn't be the idea of sharding right, or am I missing a point here, other than just spreading data instead of increasing performance?

Addition:
1. Tested it with different chunk sizes, 1 chunk, 1000 chunks. Had no impact in response time
2. monitored CPU usage and all CPU is done on the mongod, the mongos doesn't do anything. Looks like when mongod is querying a sharded collection (query coming from mongos), it has a big CPU penatly compared to a query on the same set done directly on mongod.
3. Sniffed the query, but the query is identical from mongos to mongod before sharding and after sharding.

4. Another interesting finding! Look at the proces below:

`mongos> db.testcol.find({field1: {$gte: 0}},{_id:0,field1:1}).explain();
    {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor field1_1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 5000000,
            "nscannedObjects" : 0,
            "nscanned" : 5000000,
            "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 0,
            "nscannedAllPlans" : 5000000,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : true,
            "nYields" : 6,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "millis" : 4660,
            "indexBounds" : {
                    "field1" : [
                            [
                                    0,
                                    1.7976931348623157e+308
                            ]
                    ]
            },
            "server" : "jvangaalen-PC:27020",
            "millis" : 4660
    }
    mongos> sh.shardCollection("testdb.testcol",{field1:1});
    { "collectionsharded" : "testdb.testcol", "ok" : 1 }
    mongos> db.testcol.find({field1: {$gte: 0}},{_id:0,field1:1}).explain();
    {
            "clusteredType" : "ParallelSort",
            "shards" : {
                    "192.168.11.250:27020" : [
                            {
                                    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor field1_1",
                                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                                    "n" : 5000000,
                                    "nscannedObjects" : 5000000,
                                    "nscanned" : 5000000,
                                    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 5000000,
                                    "nscannedAllPlans" : 5000000,
                                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                                    "indexOnly" : true,
                                    "nYields" : 10,
                                    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                                    "millis" : 9378,
                                    "indexBounds" : {
                                            "field1" : [
                                                    [
                                                            0,
                                                            1.7976931348623157e+308
                                                    ]
                                            ]
                                    },
                                    "server" : "jvangaalen-PC:27020"
                            }
                    ]
            },
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor field1_1",
            "n" : 5000000,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "nYields" : 10,
            "nscanned" : 5000000,
            "nscannedAllPlans" : 5000000,
            "nscannedObjects" : 5000000,
            "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 5000000,
            "millisShardTotal" : 9378,
            "millisShardAvg" : 9378,
            "numQueries" : 1,
            "numShards" : 1,
            "indexBounds" : {
                    "field1" : [
                            [
                                    0,
                                    1.7976931348623157e+308
                            ]
                    ]
            },
            "millis" : 9426
    }`

Before sharding: `4660 ms` response times.
After sharding: `9426 ms` response times.

The index is used the same way. One difference is the `nscannedobjects` which was `0`, and now is `5000000` (all documents). Why is `nscannedobjects` not `0` after sharding? This could be the cause of the extra CPU

Comment: the query is your problem. your query is scatter-gather, not targeted and I'm guessing that it has to scan almost the entire collection (300ms is *very* slow). and you are doing it on a single shard and you've put mongos in the middle. try more targeted query, and try it with multiple threads, multiple mongos' and more shards.

Comment: What do you mean with a targetted query? It is slow because of the $gte option. And it is scanning the entire collection because the entire collection is in the result. When you query everything its 10 to 20ms, but that is not the point. This is just an example collection/query.

This is just an example that shows querying to a sharded collection has a performance penalty when queried over mongos (for no reason?).
When you add a second shard (new mongod) and distribute the data evenly, the response times drop by half. But then you have the same response times when without running a shard. So

Comment: targeted is when the shard key is part of the query - when you have many shards untargeted queries have to be sent to all the shards and then results assembled back together on mongos. targeted queries are just relayed to single mongos.  And "penalty" seems for no reason because you only have one shard (but you still have overhead of going through mongos and config servers).  If you had many shards the overhead would be very small compared to query times.

Comment: Forgot to mention when I query on a non sharded collection over mongos, the response times are fine (same as on mongod). In the example you can clearly see that when you enable sharding on a collection, the response times increases significantly.

Comment: In the example the query is targetted. There is only one field (field1) which is in the query.
I have done some performance tests, and for some reason all load is going to mongod. When running the query from mongos, mongod uses twice as much CPU as when directly running the query on mongod. This is strange, because the response set is the same. Also tried the performance test through mongos just before the collection was sharded and then the CPU usage was half on mongod